# Issue with mysql subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

I am confused on how to make a sql query which will show student details who is taking subject that has been taught by a particular lecturer.

There is 5 table is my db.

Subject (`subjectCode`, `subjectName`, `creditHour`, `studyMode`)

Student (`stdID,`stdName`)

Lecturer (`lecID,`lecName`)

Lecturer-subject  (`lec_subID`, `lec_userID`, `subjectID`)

Student-subject  (`std_subID`, `student_userID`, `subjectCode`)

Comment: Yes and what are the columns what is the data ? what did you tried ?

Comment: I have edit the post with the column name.

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply the `join` and `WHERE` clause to get the data you want.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    Sturent.stdName as StudentName, 
    Subject.subjectName as SubjectName, 
    Lecturer.lecName as LecturerName, 
    Subject.creditHour, 
    Subject.studyMode  
FROM 
  Student JOIN Student-subject 
   ON student.stdID= Student-subject.student_userID
  JOIN Subject 
   ON Student-subject.subjectCode = subject.subjectCode
  JOIN Lecturer-subject 
   ON Lecturer-subject.subjectID = subject.subjectCode
  JOIN Lecturer 
   ON Lecturer-subject.lec_userID = lectrer.lecID
 WHERE
    Lecturer.lecName = 'some lecturer name'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select Sturent.stdName as StudentName, 
    Subject.subjectName as SubjectName, 
    Lecturer.lecName as LecturerName, 
    Subject.creditHour as CreditHour,
    Subject.studyMode as StudyMode from Student
    join Student-subject on student.stdID= Student-subject.student_userID
    join Subject on Student-subject.subjectCode = subject.subjectCode
    join Lecturer-subject on Lecturer-subject.subjectID = subject.subjectCode
    join Lecturer on Lecturer-subject.lec_userID = lectrer.lecID
```

or

```
select Sturent.stdName as StudentName, 
    Subject.subjectName as SubjectName, 
    Lecturer.lecName as LecturerName, 
    Subject.creditHour as CreditHour,
    Subject.studyMode as StudyMode from Student, Student-subject, 
Subject, Lecturer-subject, Lecturer 
where student.stdID= Student-subject.student_userID
    and Student-subject.subjectCode = subject.subjectCode
    and Lecturer-subject.subjectID = subject.subjectCode
    and Lecturer-subject.lec_userID = lectrer.lecID
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this it will work :**

Use `Inner Join`

```
Select t1.`stdId`,t1.`stdName`,t2.`std_subID`,t3.`subjectName`,t3.`creditHour`,t3.`studyMode`,t4.`lec_subID`,t5.`lecName` from Student t1
JOIN Student-subject t2 ON t2.`student_userId`=t1.`stdID`
JOIN Subject t3 ON t3.`subjectCode`=t2.`subjectCode`
JOIN Lecturer-subject t4 ON t4.`subjectID`=t2.`std_subID`
JOIN Lecture t5 ON t5.`lecID`=t4.`lec_userID`
```